# ¿Como hago para exportar con procedimiento almacenado un excel en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-excel

Estoy intentado exportar un excel con un procedimiento almacenado que tengo creado , para esto le envió los parámetros y todo bien , me devuelve un array completo , pero hay algunos valores null.

**Entonces hago lo siguiente (ejecuto la consulta con función estática )**

```
 $datos_mmu = S_Reporte_MMU_Cedente::get_reporte_mmu_cedente($id_cedente,$id_cartera,$tipo_mmu,$tipo_reporte);
```

Luego le paso los datos con `use` en *Maatwebsite/excel* (tengo exportado el facade de excel), y lo hago de esta manera:

```
return Excel::create('Reporte Mmu', function($excel) use ($datos_mmu){
    $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ($datos_mmu) {
        $sheet->fromArray($datos_mmu);
    });
})->export('xls');
```

**Pero cuando intento descargar me da el error**

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Entonces no se si me da ese error porque tengo valores null o porque se hace de otra manera.El array tiene que ser dinámico ya que hago todo esto con procedimientos almacenados y las columnas pueden cambiar.

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no resulta.

```
$array_data = [];
        for ($c = 0;$c<sizeof($datos_mmu);$c++)
        {
            foreach ($datos_mmu[$c] as $i=>$cedente)
            {
                $array[$i] = (array)$cedente;
            }

            array_merge($array_data,$array);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno resulta que después de tanto buscar llegue a la conclusión de que se hacia de la siguiente manera de forma dinámica

```
 $array_data = [];

        //formar array con llave de nombre de columnas para exportar
        foreach((array)$datos_mmu as $datos){
            foreach((array)$datos as $llave => $valor){
                $columnas_excel[$llave]=$valor;
            }
            array_push($array_data,$columnas_excel);
        }
```

Primero declaro un `$array_data` vacio para luego hacer `push` he ir ingresando los array.

**Después con dos foreach**

El primero es que tomo los datos datos que tiene las llaves y los datos, Ejemplo:

```
array:1039 [▼
  0 => {#1053 ▼
    +"NombreColumna1": 000000
    +"NombreColumna2": "valor"
    +"NombreColumna3": "valor"
  }
  1 => {#1054 ▶}
```

Algo así, luego con el segundo foreach lo recorro internamente uno por uno para formar el array y que quede así

```
array:1039 [▼
  0 => array:25 [▼
    "NombreColumna1": 000000
    "NombreColumna2": "valor"
    "NombreColumna3": "valor"
  ]
  1 => array:25 [▶]
```

Y una vez formado puedo pasar la variable que forme la cual seria `$array_data` y me descargará el archivo. Espero que les sirva saludos.